# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 7386 (RenderThread), pid 7349 (package.name)

Tags: android

today I encountered the following error:

> "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in
> tid 7386 (RenderThread), pid 7349 (package.name)."

I faced this issue when attempting to open the app inspection (network inspector) in Android Hedgehog. Does anyone have suggestions on how to debug this error?

I am seeking assistance in resolving this issue so that I can effectively use the network inspector to debug my apps.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using any NDKs in your app? (C/C++ code)

Comment: i don't think so, i am just using kotlin in my project...